# How to apply styles on input type=file button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

I want to apply styles on input type=file's upload button to make it attractive as like bootstrap buttons. Is there any way to apply styles on this button. Is there any support for it in bootstrap ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common solution would be give your input[file] a `opacity:0` and `postion:absolute`(make sure the parent element has `position:relative`), then let it appear on your normal bootstrap button.

See this [demo](http://jsbin.com/aCEsOt/2/) I create for you.

Comment: There must be the selected file name, not just the button

Comment: then you have to use JavaScript to do so, bind `change` event to your file button