# React custom browse button with selected file being shown

Tags: forms, file, reactjs, button, upload

I want the browse button class same as Upload button: className='button-normal', what should i do

```js
<form name="uploadForm">
  <input name='uploadFile' id='uploadFile' type='file' style={{marginTop: '1%'}}  onChange={this.check}/>
   <br/>
  <input type="button" value="Upload" style={{marginTop: '1%'}} className='button-normal' onClick={this.upload}/>
</form>
```

Comment: for what purpose you want the class name ?? for styling or any other ?

Comment: for style, I was required all button are the same in our website, however, I don't know how to make the browse button same as others.

Comment: you can directly apply the styling that u want, by assigning any other class name or by inline styling, if i am not wrong ?

Comment: for type of 'file' input, which not only a button but with a field behind, and 'no selected file' aside, cannot just apply the same class

Comment: check this, may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020013/how-to-apply-styles-on-input-type-file-button

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using `<label htmlFor=[fileInputID] ....>` to pretend and control Browse Button, hid the real Browse Button, and added a new disabled input to show the uploaded file name.

However, though I made the label looks like button, it's still not quite like a button, I hope the type of input is "button" but can still work the same as htmlFor, grateful if you have any idea to share.

```js
check: function() {
 document.getElementById("name").placeholder = document.getElementById("uploadFile").files[0].name;
    },
///
<form>
 <input name='uploadFile' id='uploadFile' type='file' style={{marginTop: '8px', fontSize:'17px', float: 'left'}}  onChange={this.check} display= 'none' />
 <label className='button-normal' style={{margin: '5px 5px 5px 5px', float: 'left'}} htmlFor='uploadFile'>Browse</label>
 <input id="name" placeholder="No file selected" style={{fontSize: '17px', marginTop:'7px'}} disabled="disabled"/>
 <input type="button" value="Upload" styles={{marginTop: '1%', float: 'left'}} className='button-normal' onClick=={this.upload}/>
</form>
```